# Error: Must provide stream that can read and seek in Large attachment from a SharePoint File with Graph

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

My C# Azure Function code gets a file from SharePoint Library and adds it as attachment to email using Graph SDK version 5.36.0.
Download The file:

```cs
Stream memStream = await _graphClient.Drives[drive.Id].Items[driveItem.Id].Content.GetAsync();
```

Create session :

```cs
var uploadSession = await _graphClient.Users[sender].Messages[draft.Id].Attachments.CreateUploadSession.PostAsync(requestBody);
```

Create the task:

```cs
var fileUploadTask =  new LargeFileUploadTask<DriveItem>(uploadSession, fileStream, maxSliceSize);
```

Get Error : `Must provide stream that can read and seek`

It used to work until a week or so ago.

Seems the upload expects a FileStream but the "Download" returns a Memory Stream (Which was OK until few days ago)

Anyone has a solution?

I did not find a way to create a FileStream without saving to disk. I have no disk in an Azure Function.

Comment: Where does `fileStream` come from, and why can't you use `MemoryStream`? Please show more code.

Comment: Make sure you response has data. The error may be due to you reading a null string.  Check if the response is 200 OK and make sure the response body is not zero bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out getting the content of the SharePoint file is not buffered by default for performance reasons. But it is not mentioned in the documentation.
So adding after the download of memStream:

```
using var bufferedStream = new MemoryStream();
await memStream.CopyToAsync(bufferedStream);//buffer the stream so that its seekable.
```

then using the "bufferedStream" for the upload, works fine.